# rbhive disables rolify, undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Role:Class

Tags: rubygems, hive

I am facing a problem with rolify when adding the gem rbhive to my Gemset. 
In method user.has_role? the following error occurs: undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Role:Class. Deleting the gem, the application runs without errors.

I used the following gems: cancancan 1.8.2, rolify 3.4.0, rbhive 1.0.2 pre and thrift 0.9.0.. I tried to reinstall all gems and different gem-versions. I need the connection to HiveServer2 through thrift client, HiveServer is not enough (this actually works).

I can't think of a possible reason for this behavior, since rbhive, rolify and cancancan don't have any dependencies on each other.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am kind of in the same situation and could use some feedback.

Comment: @ThibaudClement unfortunately not

Comment: Ok. I had the same error message and found a solution, as you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570689/rails-4-undefined-method-relation-delegate-class-for-modelclass. If nothing helps in this solution, let's jump on the chat and I will be happy to try and give you a hand.

Comment: @ThibaudClement thank you very much. In the meanwhile we switched to Java Spring so the problem is no longer existent for us.

Comment: Great for you, good luck with your project ;)