# Rails 4: undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Model:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model-view-controller, nomethoderror

I am trying to follow this coderwall tutorial about *[Creating a Scoped Invitation System for Rails](https://coderwall.com/p/rqjjca/creating-a-scoped-invitation-system-for-rails)*.

In my Rails 4 app, I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
  has_many :invitations, :class_name => "Invite", :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
  has_many :sent_invites, :class_name => "Invite", :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :invites
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Invite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

Here is the correspondance between my models and the models from the tutorial:

- `User` <=> `User`
- `Calendar` <=> `UserGroup`
- `Administration` <=> `Membership`
- `Invite` <=> `Invite`

I am now in the *Making a New Invitation* section:

- The `Invite` model has been updated with the `before_create` filter and `generate_token` method.
- The `Invites` controller has been updated with the `create` action.

However, when I visit the Calendar edit view to fill out the Invite form, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in CalendarsController#edit
undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Invite:Class
def edit
  @user = current_user
  @invite = @calendar.invites.build
  authorize @calendar
end
```

The issue seems to come from the `@invite = @calendar.invites.build` line.

—————

**UPDATE**: here is the content of my Invite model:

```
class Invite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User'

  before_create :generate_token

  def generate_token
   self.token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([self.calendar_id, self.recipient_role, Time.now, rand].join)
  end

end
```

—————

**UPDATE 2**: in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865862/rbhive-disables-rolify-undefined-method-relation-delegate-class-for-roleclas), the author explains the problem may come from CanCanCan & Rolify. I don't use these gems, but I use Pundit. Thought this would be useful in the context of my question.

—————

**UPDATE 3**: here is also the migration I used for the `Invite` model:

```
class CreateInvites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :invites do |t|
      t.string :email 
      t.integer :calendar_id
      t.integer :sender_id
      t.integer :recipient_id
      t.string :recipient_role
      t.string :token
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I am wondering if the problem could be caused by the `t.string :recipient_role`, since the `role` of a given `user` only exist in the `administration` table, for a given `calendar`: if `:recipient_role` is automatically interpreted as `recipient.role` by Rails, then maybe this is causing the error?

—————

**UPDATE 4**: here is the content of CalendarsController:

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_calendar, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /calendars
  # GET /calendars.json
  def index
    @user = current_user
    @calendars = @user.calendars.all
  end

  # GET /calendars/1
  # GET /calendars/1.json
  def show
    @user = current_user
    @calendar = @user.calendars.find(params[:id])
    authorize @calendar
  end

  # GET /calendars/new
  def new
    @user = current_user
    @calendar = @user.calendars.new
    authorize @calendar
  end

  # GET /calendars/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = current_user
    @invite = @calendar.invites.build
    authorize @calendar
  end

  # POST /calendars
  # POST /calendars.json
def create
  @user = current_user
  @calendar = @user.calendars.create(calendar_params)
  authorize @calendar
  respond_to do |format|
    if @calendar.save
      current_user.set_default_role(@calendar.id, 'Owner')
      format.html { redirect_to calendar_path(@calendar), notice: 'Calendar was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @calendar }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @calendar.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

  # PATCH/PUT /calendars/1
  # PATCH/PUT /calendars/1.json
  def update
    @user = current_user
    @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:id])
    authorize @calendar
    respond_to do |format|
      if @calendar.update(calendar_params)
        format.html { redirect_to calendar_path(@calendar), notice: 'Calendar was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @calendar }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @calendar.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /calendars/1
  # DELETE /calendars/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = current_user
    @calendar.destroy
    authorize @calendar
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to calendars_url, notice: 'Calendar was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_calendar
      @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def calendar_params
      params.require(:calendar).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

—————

**UPDATE 5**: here are the server logs:

```
Started GET "/calendars/2/edit" for ::1 at 2015-09-14 11:44:13 -0700
Processing by CalendarsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Calendar Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Invite:Class):
  app/controllers/calendars_controller.rb:30:in `edit'


  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (6.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (68.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (39.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (94.2ms)
```

—————

**UPDATE 6**: I just realized I did not have

```
def invite_params
  params.require(:invite)
end
```

in the `Invites` controller: could this be the root of the problem here?

—————

Any idea about what this error message mean and how to fix the issue?

Comment: Could you show full backtrace of the error you get? It would also be helpful if I can see contents of your CalendarsController. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, I just added the full code of the `CalendarsController` and the server logs. Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. Try updating all of your gems. Try hardcoding a class name on the `invites` association. Try commenting out all of the associations then uncommenting them one at a time until it breaks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking a look at it James, really appreciate it. I will try what you suggest.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem was tricky to identify, especially just from the content of the question.

***THE PROBLEM***

The reason why I was getting the `undefined method 'relation_delegate_class' for Invite:Class` error is because `Invite` was no longer considered to be a model by Rails.

***THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM***

When I created the `Invite` mailer, I ran `rails g mailer Invite` instead of `rails g mailer InviteMailer`.

Because of this, `Invite` as a mailer override `Invite` as a model, hence creating errors as soon as methods were applied to instances of the `Invite` model.

***HOW WE FIGURED IT OUT***

One of my friends, who is way more experienced with programming than I am, identified the problem by tweaking the `@invite = @calendar.invites.build` line that was causing the error.

This led us to eventually run `Invite.first` in the rails console: while we should have got either an instance of the `Invite` class, or nil, we actually got an error.

Since `.first` should be a valid method on any ActiveRecord model, we realized that `Invite` was not a considered to be a model by Rails.

***HOW WE FIXED IT***

Once we had identified the issue, fixing it was pretty straightforward:

- We changed the name of the `Invite` mailer from `invite.rb` to `invite_mailer.rb`
- In the newly renamed `invite_mailer.rb` file, we replaced `class Invite < ApplicationMailer` with `class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer`

I hope this can be useful to other Stack Overflow users who might get a similar `relation_delegate_class` error.

Comment: Thanks a lot K M Rakibul Islam. It took some time but we fixed it!

Comment: Ran into the exact same problem with a mailer called invite. Thanks for the detailed answer and for saving me some time.

Comment: Thank you!  Same kind of 'naming' issue with my project.  Appreciate the detailed response.

Comment: I had the same issue and it was actually related to a class we had named "Messager.rb" for the API messages. A few months later we created a model called "Message" and was receiving this error. I figured out pretty quick that it was because we had 2 classes with the same name. Naming is key, lol... renamed Message to ApiMessage.rb

Answer (score 1):

It also happen if you forget to inherit your model from ActiveRecord.
Thus it becomes just a simple ruby class.

```
class MyPlainModel
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another cause is that your sti column is pointing to an invalid column class. I somehow had ended up with:

```
=> #<Mailerlite::Subscriber:0x00005559d469bd00
...
 user_id: 2777,
 user_type: "NilClass",
...
>
```

Causing `NoMethodError: undefined method 'relation_delegate_class' for NilClass:Class` when trying to load the `user` relation.

Simple enough fix by changing the `user_type` column to be `nil` or the correct classname.