# Rails 4: ActionMailer Preview cannot find Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, preview

I am trying to preview an email and I'm running into some trouble.

```
# test/mailers/previews/food_order_preview.rb
class FoodOrderPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
    def food_order_email
        @food_order = FoodOrder.first  # line with error
        @fields = @food_order.with_values
        FoodOrder.food_order_email(order, fields)
    end
end
```

When I load the preview I see:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `first' for FoodOrder:Class):
  test/mailers/previews/food_order_preview.rb:6:in `food_order_email'
```

**Why would this occur?**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570689/rails-4-undefined-method-relation-delegate-class-for-modelclass) I was able to diagnose the issue.  There was an issue with the migration I ran while creating the `mailer`.

> **THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM**
>
> When I created the Invite mailer, I ran rails g mailer Invite instead
>   of rails g mailer InviteMailer.
>
> Because of this, Invite as a mailer override Invite as a model, hence
>   creating errors as soon as methods were applied to instances of the
>   Invite model.
>
> **HOW WE FIXED IT**
>
> Once we had identified the issue, fixing it was pretty
>   straightforward:
>
> - We changed the name of the Invite mailer from invite.rb to
>     invite_mailer.rb
> - In the newly renamed invite_mailer.rb file, we
>     replaced class Invite < ApplicationMailer with class InviteMailer <
>     ApplicationMailer

Hope this helps someone else!